# What's the most efficient way of programming a conversion table algorithm

Tags: vba, algorithm, logic

I'm wondering what your opinion is of the following:

I need to convert 1 to 3 values and make it into a single value while using a conversion table:

[image]

Here is an example:

Low + High + High = Medium

Medium + Medium + High = High

What do you guys think is the most efficient way of programming this algorithm? The language I'll be using is VBA (Excel)

I already thought about making a lot of nested `If` statements, but my programming sense tells me there's an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Most efficient" is very subjective. What do you pretend? Compact code, fast code, ...

Comment: Can you use the above and find the combination in that and shift off to the left?  Also look at grouping the logic, "so if 1,2,3 are equal, it is the value, 3 or 2 lows is medium, no lows I always high"

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Compact is indeed the most desired

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Correct, find the matching combination and to the left/right is the converted value

Comment: I was suggesting that as a solution.  Edit to my next comment "so if 1,2,3 are equal, it is the value, 3 or 2 lows is low, no lows is always high"

Comment: @krapton Lol!!! "most desired" is also subjective!!!

Comment: @Nathan_Sav This table is just an image, the question is, what is the shortest way of making this into an algorithm. I thought your comment was about how the table is used

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ it's still an answer to your question. You asked in what way to interpret "efiicient".

Comment: add the table to excel or wherever and use it's native lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a need for a table ?

If you take the sum of the three values, you get the following correspondence:

```
Low: 3, 4 or 5
Medium: 6
High: 7, 8, or 9.
```

Code:

```
        P = V1 + V2 + V3
        If P < 6 Then
            R = 1
        ElseIf P < 7 Then
            R = 2
        Else
            R = 3
        End If
```

You can also directly tabulate the sum, or use the formula

```
Sgn(V1 + V2 + V3 - 6) + 2
```

(will be hard to do more compact, as the three variables must somehow appear).

---

Actually, as the scores are symmetric, the initial table could already have been been compressed as

```
111 => 1
112 => 1
113 => 1
122 => 1
123 => 2
222 => 2
223 => 3
233 => 3
333 => 3
```

---

**Final note**:

If the scores are represented on a `(-1, 0, +1)` scale, the formula simplifies to

```
Sgn(V1 + V2 + V3)
```

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't think about the possibility of not using the table. Thanks!

Comment: @Krapton: also note that my observation about the sum 7 was wrong, so that the problem is even easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub heres_an_idea()

Dim dicLow As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dicMed As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dicHigh As New Scripting.Dictionary

dicLow.Add "LLL", ""
dicLow.Add "LLM", ""
dicLow.Add "LLH", ""

dicMed.Add "MMM", ""

dicHigh.Add "HHH", ""

If dicLow.Exists("MMM") Then
    'low
    Debug.Print "low"
ElseIf dicMed.Exists("MMM") Then
    'med
    Debug.Print "med"
ElseIf dicHigh.Exists("MMM") Then
    'high
    Debug.Print "high"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

"Most efficient" is very subjective. I would put all values into an array (are not that many) and access it with index based in your values.

1. Consider `index = FirstValue + SecondValue*3 + ThirdValue*9`

   FirstValue: 0=L1, 1=L2, 2=L3

   SecondValue, ThirdValue: 0=L1, 1=L2, 2=L3, 3=Unused

   (This set is not optimal as you may combine Unused second with used third, but you can truncate these values!)

   This will result in 3*(3*4+1)=39 combination, a small string!
2. Put all your result in a table and compose a string:

   `myData = "000001011001012122011122122001012122012"` where 0=Low, 1=Meddium, 2=High
3. Define your function (and type if you wish):

VBA code:

```
Enum myType
     L1 = 0
     L2 = 1
     L3 = 2
End Enum

Function getValue(ByVal V1 As myType, Optional ByVal V2 As myType = 3, Optional ByVal V3 As myType = 3)
        getValue = Array("Low", "Meddium", "High")(Mid("000001011001012122011122122001012122012", V1 + V2 * 3 + V3 * 9 + 1, 1))
End Function
```

This will be fast and short. Just need to work your data a little before use!

Comment: Thanks! I got this as an assignment, and this was part of an PowerPoint presentation. I didn't yet put this in an excel table because i wasn't sure that was the best way to handle this, but you answer is interesting!